# Calling FB Greeting from Bot Framework

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, botframework

I was trying to create FB Gretting using C# SDK and sending the curl request according to FB documentation here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/thread-settings/greeting-text

However, seems that there is no response from FB. Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks

```
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    int i = 0;
    /// <summary>
    /// POST: api/Messages
    /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
    /// </summary>
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {

        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            //await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.TheQnAMakerDialog());
        }
        else
        {                
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }

    private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
    {
        if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
        {
            // Implement user deletion here
            // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
            // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
            // Not available in all channels
            var callFB=SendFBGreeting();                
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle add/remove from contact lists
            // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
        {
            // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
        {
        }

        return null;
    }

    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendFBGreeting()
    {
        var payload = @"{
            ""setting_type"": ""greeting"",
            ""greeting"": {
                ""text"": ""Timeless apparel for the masses.""
            }
        }";
        var stringPayload = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload));
        var httpContent = new StringContent(stringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            // Do the actual request and await the response
            var httpResponse = await client.PostAsync("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=xxx", httpContent);

            // If the response contains content we want to read it!
            if (httpResponse.Content != null)
            {
                var responseContent = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            }
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not return a **ConversationUpdate** event. Try to  call **SendFBGreeting()** elsewhere.

Keep in mind greeting text will be shown **before** the user **Get Started**, So even if you do get ConversationUpdate event, it won't matter in this case.